# default_url_options not called (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I've set default_url_options in my ApplicationController class to add a default year parameter in the url.

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def default_url_options
    {locale: I18n.locale, year: session[:current_year]}
   end
 end
```

I used path helper in views to make links to controllers and action.

```
<%= link_to t('.people'), people_path %>
```

It works fine in development and production on my local computer but in production on the server the default_url_options is never called. Why ?

Edit: In development is working fine. Then, the problem is with the production. It'm going to search in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

just set it up via config file `Rails.root + config/environments/your_env.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
  host: 'http://localhost:3000', locale: I18n.locale, year: session[:current_year]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but the session doesn't exist when the environment is loaded. And I need to change the default_url_options for all path, not only for the action_mailer.